# Flutter:ListView inside ListView.builder

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to bring a List of containers and i want to change the details inside this list of containers using fire store. But when i am running the program the page is showing blank.  [The output i want is like this image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkAIf.jpg) 
[The output i am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9O79.jpg)  And my second question is how to add images to the field inside the firestore.
Thanks in advance, it is really hard to publish a question in stack overflow.

```
      body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Event').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         const Text('No Event');
        } 
        else if(snapshot.hasError){ const Text('No data avaible right now'); } 
        else {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot myEvent = snapshot.data.documents[index];

                 
                return ListView(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //1st box

                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(
                          SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 4),
                      child: Container(
                        child: new FittedBox(
                          child: Material(
                            // color: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 14.0,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                            shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left:
                                            SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal *
                                                4),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 8.0),
                                          child: Container(
                                              child: Text(
                                            '${myEvent['date_1']}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black54,
                                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                                fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight.bold),
                                          )),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 8.0),
                                          child: Container(
                                              child: Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment
                                                    .spaceEvenly,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                '${myEvent['title_1']}',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              )),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                '${myEvent['details_1_a']}',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                ),
                                              )),
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                '${myEvent['details_1_b']}',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                ),
                                              )),
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                      SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 18,
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width:
                                      SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 60,
                                  height:
                                      SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 55,
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      '${myEvent['image_1']}',
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    //2nd box

                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(
                          SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 4),
                      child: Container(
                        child: new FittedBox(
                          child: Material(
                            // color: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 14.0,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                            shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left:
                                            SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal *
                                                4),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 8.0),
                                          child: Container(
                                              child: Text(
                                            '${myEvent['date_2']}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black54,
                                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                                fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight.bold),
                                          )),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 8.0),
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceEvenly,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Container(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                  '${myEvent['title_2']}',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold),
                                                )),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10,
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                  '${myEvent['details_2_a']}',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  ),
                                                )),
                                                Container(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                  '${myEvent['details_2_b']}',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  ),
                                                )),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width:
                                      SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 18,
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width:
                                      SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 60,
                                  height:
                                      SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 55,
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                    child:  Image.network(
                                      '${myEvent['image_2']}',
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! I would suggest reducing the code in your question to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help others read it more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.I made like this so others can understand what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the second listview, but if you do, try this:

```
body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Event').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         const Text('No Event');
        } 
        else if(snapshot.hasError){ const Text('No data avaible right now'); } 
        else {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot myEvent = snapshot.data.documents[index];

                 
                return ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //1st box

                    ...
```

Comment: I was trying to bring 5 boxes and now there are 25 boxes with most of them are showing null

Comment: In that 25 boxes how to remove the boxes which is null